# How does java global variable work?

Tags: java, global-variables

I am making `Othello` game in java and have problem to switch other player when `enter` pressed. I declared global variable `public static int counter;` which will increment when enter pressed.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
move = s.nextLine();
// enter to forfeit
if(move.equals("")){
    if(counter%2 == 0){
        whiteEnterForfeit = turn(board, "White", "W", "B");
        printBoard(board);
        counter++;
        }
    if(counter%2 == 1) {
        blackEnterForfeit = turn(board, "Black", "B", "W");
        printBoard(board);
        counter++;
        }
 }

/* If coordinate is typed like 2,4 I will be recorded at right spot on the board.

else if(!move.equals("")){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(move, ",");
    rowMove = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    colMove = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
*/
```

So once I press enter twice in row, it is supposed to print out `Black-White-Black`. However, mine prints out `Black-White-White.....`. What I think about `static` global variable is that any classes or methods can access and modify its value.

I also increment `counter` when each player successfully plays. 
Since its code is over 300lines, you can find it on github (https://github.com/misonam03/TIL/blob/master/Java/Othello.java).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post an SSCCE http://sscce.org **here** so that we can analyse your problem.

Comment: What did you find when you tried debugging?

Comment: @shmosel I am using eclipse and does not show any `red` signal. Does it still have bug?

Comment: That's not what [debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) means.

Comment: @shmosel I don't know how to. I just clicked debug button and it does not show any warning...

Comment: Click the link in my comment and learn how to debug. It's one of the most critical skills you'll need as a programmer.

Comment: @shmosel Okay. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to have to download this code and take a look. I think I see extra curly braces. Also if you don't know how to use a debugger. Logging statements are the next best thing.

Comment: @ndrone ty for your help!

Comment: @Jay why not use an else with your `if(counter%2 == 0)` because either the result of the mod is 0 or 1 there is no other possibility. Also, since there are only two players why not just use a `boolean` and set it to the opposite of itself with each turn. E.g. `boolean isWhiteTurn = true;` ... `isWhiteTurn = !isWhiteTurn;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hava a recursion here, and then your counter never get incremented:

```
if(counter%2 == 0){
    whiteEnterForfeit = turn(board, "White", "W", "B");
    printBoard(board);
    counter++;
}
```

If you move the counter++ before the call you get the print right but eventually you will get a StackOverflowError because the way you implemented the recursion.

I think this video series can help you a lot. It's for a C# GO Game, but it's very similar to what you are doing: [Roy Osherove - Building a Go Game Engine With TDD and Pair Programming - Part 1](http://osherove.com/videos/2012/6/25/video-part-1-building-a-go-game-engine-with-tdd-and-pair-pro.html)

Comment: Ty for advice! The reason I use global variable in here is to avoid recursion problem and it seems like it does not work I meant

Comment: Take this as a hint that global variables are **evil**! They cause hart to track problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `else` keyword instead of the `if`. This will fix it because currently, the counter is being incremented when it is even, which will make it odd (and so the second `if` statement runs).

```
if(counter%2 == 0){
    whiteEnterForfeit = turn(board, "White", "W", "B");
    printBoard(board);
    counter++;
} else {
    blackEnterForfeit = turn(board, "Black", "B", "W");
    printBoard(board);
    counter++;
}
```

Making the second `if` an `else` instead will stop both from being run.

Comment: It still shows Black-White-White-White. I think what one of other guys said was right. He mentioned recursion

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to write the code this way:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
move = s.nextLine();
// enter to forfeit
if(move.equals("")){
    if(counter%2 == 0){
        whiteEnterForfeit = turn(board, "White", "W", "B");
    }
    if(counter%2 == 1) {
        blackEnterForfeit = turn(board, "Black", "B", "W");
    }
    printBoard(board);
    counter++;
 }
```